# Как воспроизводить видео с камеры на VideoPlayer

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть камера "видеонаблюдения" за комнатой. В соседней комнате есть GameObject (монитор) с VideoPlayer ом на котором должна быть ТЕКУЩАЯ запись с камеры. И теперь вопрос как это сделать? (камера называется camera173 а "монитор" monitor173)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте вашу "камеру видеонаблюдения" дополнительной Camera в Unity. Камеры в Unity могут рендерить не только на экран, но и в текстуру. Именно последний подход и должен вам помочь. Его можно реализовать с помощью Render Texture. Создайте Render Texture и настройте вашу камеру, чтобы она отрисовывала в вашу Renderer Texture - у компонента Camera есть поле "Target Texture".

Далее можете настроить ваш VideoPlayer, чтобы он показывал Render Texture, которую вы создали. Для этого можете посмотреть в сторону свойства [VideoPlayer.targetTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-targetTexture.html).

Кроме того, использование VideoPlayer необязательно. Вы можете использовать Render Texture как обычную текстуру и добавить ее на любой GameObject. Пример такого решения вы можете посмотреть в [этом видео-туториале](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pA7ZC8owaeo) (туториал на английском, но там все понятно и по картинке).

Дополнительную информацию о Render Texture можно почитать в официальной документации: [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html) и [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html).